# Define polynomials over rational function fields in sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomials

I am struggling a bit to represent a polynomial with coefficients that are rational functions in sympy:

For example: `p_t = Poly((y-(x**(1/2)))*(y-1*x**2),y)`
has the domain "Ex". And i cant give it a more specific domain such as `ZZ[x**0.5]` or `ZZ(x)`

Is it possible to give this polynomial a more specific domain? Because when working with

```
p_t = Poly((y-(x**(1/2))),y,domain="ZZ[x**0.5]")
```

it works just fine.

So @Physmatik already clarified how to solve my example. There is still the question left for the general case, for example:

```
Poly((y-(x**Rational(0.5)))*(y-(x**Rational(0.4))),y)
```

gets evaluated to:

```
Poly(y**2 + (-x**(3602879701896397/9007199254740992) - sqrt(x))*y + x**(8106479329266893/9007199254740992), y, domain='EX')
```

May follow up question is especially if i can define these polynomials with know the generator.

Edit: I am sorry, I think this one is on me, I thought that Rational(1,2) is the same as Rational(0.5) which it does not seem to be.

Comment: preeeeetty sure you wanted `((y-1)*x**2)`, not `(y-1*x**2)`? What you're showing right now just reduces to `(y - √x)(y - x²)`.

Comment: If I try `Poly((y-(x**sp.Rational(1, 2)))*(y-1*x**2),domain='ZZ[x**(1/2)]')` I get `Poly(-x**2*y + y**2 - sqrt(x)*y + (sqrt(x))**5, x, y, sqrt(x), domain='ZZ[sqrt(x)]')`.
Are you sure you specify your generators correctly?

Comment: Don't you rather mean `ZZ<sqrt(2)>`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No I mean x**0.5. I think Physmatik solves my question, and its simply a matter of writing Rational(1,2) instead of 0.5.

Comment: @Ragon I didn't know (or don't remember) that. Is it the set of polynomials in sqrt(x) with coefficients in Z?

Comment: The domain ZZ[x**(1/2)] describes the set of powerseries of the form sum a_i x^(i/2)

Comment: @Physmatik thank you for this tip! The Problems still arise when working with even a little bit more complex polynomials

Comment: It's not `Rational(0.4)` (that conversion can get really ugly because of how floats are represented internally), it should be `Rational(4, 10)`. Use only integers to specify your rationals.